# How to fix "Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option `dvips'"?

Tags: xetex, hyperref, errors, dvips

I'm having this Error when I try to compile my `.tex` file with `xelatex`:

```
! Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option `dvips',
(hyperref)                because XeTeX is running.

See the hyperref package documentation for explanation.
```

This is my LaTeX header

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, dvips,]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[grey, roman]{classic}

\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex % only for xelatex
\usepackage{xltxtra} % this should load both fontspec & xunicode
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont{Helvetica Neue}
\else %
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi % \ifxetex
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I removed the 'dvips', now I get:

```
! Package hyperref Error: Wrong driver option `pdftex',
(hyperref)                because pdfTeX in PDF mode is not detected.

See the hyperref package documentation for explanation.
```

Now my first latex line

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{moderncv}
```

Any clues ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't use the `dvips` option for the class (and any package). It will be passed to every package, like all class options, and tell these that they should use the DVIPS mode or driver. You however use apparently XeLaTeX which uses a different driver.

You should not explicitly state the driver in any case. The packages should nowadays be able to determine the correct driver themselves and stating a wrong one manually leads to exactly this kind of errors.

Comment: Except for `dvipdfmx` which cannot be auto-detected.

Comment: I removed dvips from my options, but it's not working for another reason, I edited my post :)

Comment: @Mr.Gando: Your new error would actually be a new problem and which should be asked as a new question instead of changing the existing one. But the answer here is simple enough: Older versions of `modernsv` used the `pdftex` driver explicitly, making it incompatible with XeLaTeX. Simply update your version to the newest one.

Comment: How is doipd remove from LexStudio?

Answer (score 3):

I have this version:

```
moderncv.cls    2011/12/23 v0.15.1 modern curriculum vitae document class
```

and do not get a problem with the driver.

Comment: Apologies for being contrary, but is this really an answer? It seems more like a comment.

Comment: fwiw, the latest version is `2013/04/29 v1.5.1`, which is also present in tex live.

Answer (score 0):

I also came across the same trouble, for I use XeLaTeX. The original .cls says: if dvips fails , turns to dvipdfm. So I would add a third option, when dvipdfm also fails , it turns to  xetex.

```
\ifTWXJZ@dvips   \TWXJZ@dvipsfalse
    \DeclareOption{dvips}{\TWXJZ@dvipstrue} \DeclareOption{dvipdfm}
{\TWXJZ@dvipsfalse}
    \DeclareOption{xetex}{\TWXJZ@dvipsfalse} % I added this sentence
```

Below is my offer of the third option:

```
\ifpdf   % We're running pdfTeX in PDF mode
  \RequirePackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\else    % We're not running pdfTeX, or running pdfTeX in DVI mode
  \ifTWXJZ@dvips
     \RequirePackage[dvips]{hyperref}
  \else
    %\RequirePackage[dvipdfm]{hyperref}    % this is the original description, which I'd prefer to modify as below:
     \if\RequirePackage[dvipdfm]{hyperref} % I added
     \else                                 % I added
        \RequirePackage[xetex]{hyperref}   % I added
```

Thank God, the problem is fixed!