# Statistics in Medicine Latex Template Problem

Tags: errors, hyperref, luatex

I am trying to use the Statistics in Medicine LaTeX template from their link [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/%28ISSN%291097-0258/homepage/la_tex_class_file.htm).

The issue is, I get the following warning when I compile their template with the matching files:

> Package hyperref Error : Wrong DVI mode driver option 'dvips',(hyperref) because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF mode. \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}

What can I do to resolve this error and compile the template successfully?

Comment: Are you trying to compile their SIMDOC.TEX file?  Which TeX engine are you using?  LuaTeX? pdfTeX? pdfLaTeX? LaTeX?

Comment: either remove the dvips option or use latex rather than pdflatex.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39943/5763. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.